# list images pushes content down

Tags: css, image

When I use images in `<li>`, the content pushes down. It's suppose to be aligned with the images. http://jsbin.com/epayo5

```
 .services-info ul li {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 39px 0;
    width: 266px;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.services-info ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    list-style-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/fb-icon.png);
}

.services-info ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
    list-style-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/twitter-icon.png);
}

.services-info ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
    list-style-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/yt-icon.png);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `background-image` instead of `list-style-image`. For example:

```
.services-info ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/fb-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then add left padding to the list item:

```
.services-info ul li {
    padding-left: 120px;
}
```

See updated [bin](http://jsbin.com/epayo5/5).

Comment: I can't change the background color though.

Comment: Sure you can. Just add a color token like `background: blue url(...) no-repeat;` or add a `background-color: blue;` declaration.

Comment: In the code, I have   background: #fff; in ul li. I'm working on a dark background. When I use background on li instead, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it's a specificity issue. See updated answer and [bin](http://jsbin.com/epayo5/5).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the background-image for your list items, and set their padding to allow space for the background image.

[Here is a jsfiddle showing how to do it.](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fk3q/1/)

**CSS:**

```
#social_network li {
    height: 95px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
li.fb {
    background-image: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/fb-icon.png');
}
li.twitter {
    background-image: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/twitter-icon.png');
}
li.yt {
    background-image: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/yt-icon.png');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="social_network">
    <li class="fb">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text
    </li>

    <li class="twitter">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </li>

    <li class="yt">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </li>
</ul>
```